# In ruby on rails is this possible to write the commonly used functions in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In ruby on rails is this possible to write the  commonly used functions in model and call it in the controller.
the function in the model should return a value to controller.

I had to write an authentication function common to several definitions in the profile controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a the function as a helper and call it in controllers

```
module AuthenticationHelper
   def authenticate
     #blah..blah..blah
   end
end
```

Include the helper in application controller and now it is available for use in all controllers.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     include AuthenticationHelper
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more.. you can add a class method to any model that can be called by anything.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.authenticate(arg1,arg2,etc)
      #blah #blah
   end
end



class MyController < ActionController::Base
   def authenticate
      MyModel.authenticate(<YOU PASS PARAMS NEEDED>)
   end
end
```